# Wordpress Admin Login Issue

Tags: wp-admin, login

**Hi Guys, hoping you can help with an issue I am having logging into a WP site.
This is the error message I get when trying to log in as Admin:**

Warning: Illegal string offset 'remember' in /homepages/13/dxxxxxxxxxx/htdocs/SITENAME/wp-includes/user.php on line 41

Warning: Cannot assign an empty string to a string offset in /homepages/13/dxxxxxxxxxx/htdocs/SITENAME/wp-includes/user.php on line 41

Warning: Illegal string offset 'user_login' in /homepages/13/dxxxxxxxxxx/htdocs/SITENAME/wp-includes/user.php on line 56

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot create references to/from string offsets in /homepages/13/d516757352/htdocs/SITENAME/wp-includes/user.php:56 Stack trace: #0 /homepages/13/d516757352/htdocs/SITENAME/wp-login.php(806): wp_signon('', '') #1 {main} thrown in /homepages/13/dxxxxxxxxxx/htdocs/SITENAME/wp-includes/user.php on line 56

**Do I need to access this via FTP?

Many thanks in advance

Kind regards**

Comment: This looks like a plugin conflict issue - have you recently installed or updated any plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating your Wordpress Manually if you are not on the current version: https://wordpress.org/support/article/updating-wordpress/

If you are on the correct version I suggest slowly deleting your most recently installed plugins. If you do not remember, I suggest slowly deleting them one by one and checking to see if you can then login. **NOTE** You do not actually have to delete the plugins, you could rename each one with a singular letter or number to simply remove them from the site but not have to reinstall upon allocating the plugin giving you an issue

To find this directory, yes you will need to login to your Cpanel at the following strand: 
public_html>wp-content>plugins

Comment: Thank you for this - I managed to replace the User.php file with the new one which allowed me access to the admin dashboard to perform the full update

Comment: Wonderful! I am glad you found access to FTP to perform such an action